# Pulling image from private container registry (Harbor) in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

I am using Harbor (https://goharbor.io/) for private container registry. I run the Harbor using docker compose, and it is working fine. I can push/ pull images to this private registry using a VM. I already used 'docker login' command to login into this Harbor repository.

For Kubernetes, I am using k3s.

Now, I want to create a pod in Kubernetes using the image in this Harbor private repository. I referred to Harbor & Kubernetes documentations (https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/working-with-projects/working-with-images/pulling-pushing-images/) & (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) to pull the image.

As mentioned in Harbor documentation:

> Kubernetes users can easily deploy pods with images stored in Harbor.
> The settings are similar to those of any other private registry. There
> are two issues to be aware of:
>
> When your Harbor instance is hosting HTTP and the certificate is
> self-signed, you must modify daemon.json on each work node of your
> cluster. For information, see
> https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry.
>
> If your pod references an image under a private project, you must
> create a secret with the credentials of a user who has permission to
> pull images from the project. For information, see
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/.

I created the daemon.json file in /etc/docker:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : "my-harbor-server:443"
}
```

As mentioned in Kubernetes documentation, I created the Secret using this command:

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Then I used a file called pod.yml to create pod (using kubectl apply -f pod.yml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: my-harbor-server/my-project/mayapp:v1.0
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
```

However, when I checked the pod status, it is showing 'ImagePullBackOff'. The pod logs shows:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "myapp" in pod "myapp" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

Is there any other step that I have to do to pull this image from Harbor private repository into Kubernetes? What is the reason that I cannot pull this image from Harbor private repository into Kubernetes?

Comment: can you crate an alpine pod from docker hub and then try to ping or call the api of the harbor instance `my-harbor-server`. I guess that you k3s can't reach that domain.

Comment: What CRI does your kubernetes environment use? Did you set the daemon.json file on every docker node?

Comment: @Vad1mo I tried it. Actually I found that need to put the certificate into the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/. Then update the certificate.

Comment: @BMitch For K3s, the default container runtime is containerd. I set the daemon.json file on every node. Also I found that need to put the certificate into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file configures the docker engine. If your CRI is not the docker shim, them this file will not apply to Kubernetes. For k3s, that is configured using `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml`. See https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry/ for details on configuring this file. It needs to be performed on each host.